# Lighting (to add lights) in gltf 2.0

Tags: blender, gltf

I´m using Blender 2.79 and I´ve been exporting using the addon provided by khronos. How possible is it to light the scene with the model, and export it?
My model has textures appearing too dark. Facebook posts appear darker.
On sandbox babylon the environment helps to light the model a little but there´s no real light source setup. How do I export my model with lights?
Also: I´m using very high value spotlights, and point lights..none of which appear at (.gbl) file export. 
Please help.

Comment: Probably better suited for https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Either way, if you're having problems with some code/model/export/whatever, people expect you to post that so that it can be discussed.

Comment: The glTF format does not yet include lights. You'll need to set them up in your scene after importing the model.

Comment: Correction: as of December 2018 glTF 2.0 now supports lightS: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_lights_punctual.